# Need assitance local storage comparison with DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage

**Page 1:** I am setting local storage on a DIV. It is getting the contents of an unordered list. This list contains different products. Olive Oil, Tomatoes, etc.

**Page 2:** I am retrieving the local storage contents. On this page, i have a DIV that shows an item name. If the DIV title on this page exactly matches an item from the unordered list on page 1 (Olive Oil for example), how can I append the entire list from page 1 in a new DIV on page 2?

Here is my code to get an idea:

**Page 1:**

```
localStorage["productID"] = JSON.stringify($("#recipeIngredients li").html());
```

**Page 2:**

```
var prodTitle = $('#productTitle').text();

if (localStorage["productID"] != null) {
    var contentsOfOldDiv = JSON.parse(localStorage["productID"]);    
} 

if (prodTitle === contentsOfOldDiv) {
    $("divWhereIwantStuffDisplayed").html(contentsOfOldDiv);
}
```

Comment: Stringifying html? You do not have JSON....

Comment: thats all inside JSON im just not showing everything

Comment: It is HTML markup, not JSON

Comment: so thats unnecessary?

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to do JSON parsing, you have a string, store the string and read the string.

Store it:

```
localStorage["productID"] = $("#recipeIngredients li").html();
```

Read it:

```
var contentsOfOldDiv = localStorage["productID"] || null;
```

Comment: thank you im still learning but this doesnt solve my overall issue

Comment: What is your overall issue?

Comment: i need to do an if statement on page 2. if the page title from page 2 contains an exact match from the list on page1, i need to show the list on page 2

Comment: Well you are not comparing a title, you are comparing something to the html of the li...

Comment: Maybe if you gave a complete sample, than I could help you solve the overall issue.

Comment: the title on page 2 is "Olive Oil". the li in page 1 has "Olive Oil" in the list. i just need to find a way to check for a match between the two and show that entire list on page 2

Comment: Do you realize you are storing just one li? Does that `li` have just the text Olive Oil or does it have more than just that? Again can't read minds since the crystal ball is in the shop, would be better with a complete sample.

Comment: i need to store all the list items actually. one li has "Olive Oil" another has "Tomatoes" and so on. basically just looking if it contains the exact name that matches the page title